# Specify a Parent-Child relationship in EF Core without using identity columns

Tags: entity-framework-core, hierarchical-data

Specify a Parent-Child relationship in EF Core without using identity columns

What's an efficient way within Entity Framework Core 5 (C#) to work with the data in a hierarchial table that is linked via non-identity columns.

Here's my primary class:

```
public class ServiceProvider
{ 
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string ParentSPCode { get; set; }        
    public string SPCode { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string City { get; set; }        
    public string State { get; set; }        
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }        
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

The SPCode value is unique, which I enforce via C# code.  The ParentSPCode may be null or must match an existing SPCode.  Again I enforce this via C# code.

I want this table to hold any number of levels of parent-child (1 or more) records, as defined by ParentSPCode-SPCode pairs.

I can retrieve these records via a complex hierarchy of LINQ "joins", but I am thinking there must be a cleaner way by defining the appropriate EF Core 5 relationship.

If I was in SQL Server, I would do this via a CTE.

I want to be able to bring in the child records in a manner similar to .Include(q => q.ParentSPCode == x.SPCode).

Comment: EF is designed to work with Key columns in order to establish relationships. If you don't use the actual `Id` at all, you may as well tell EF, that `SPCode` is your key. I don't know how to teach EF about relations that are not key-defined.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys